# Edit multi-select field from front end

Tags: templating, users, form

I'm trying to set up a front end user profile that will allow the user to use the multi-select field. When I update from the CP, the changes are reflected on the front end, but this isn't working when trying to update from the front end form.

Is there anything I'm missing?

```
{% set languageOptionsIds = user.providerLanguages %}

<label for="providerLanguages">What languages do you work with?</label>
{% for option in currentUser.providerLanguages.options %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="providerLanguages" name="fields[providerLanguages][]"
    {% if option.selected in languageOptionsIds %}checked{% endif %} value="{{ option.selected }}">{{ option.label }}
    </input>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can get the options directly from the 'currentUser' entry, without referring to 'user' separately (they are likely the same thing in this case anyway):

```
<label for="providerLanguages">What languages do you work with?</label>
{% for option in currentUser.providerLanguages.options %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="providerLanguages" name="fields[providerLanguages][]"
    {% if option.selected %}checked{% endif %} value="{{ option.value }}">
        {{ option.label }}
    </input>
{% endfor %}
```

The value is also available as 'option.value' instead of 'option.selected'.

Comment: `user` is deprecated. `currentUser` is the way to go.

Comment: @Brad what will the variable be called when viewing or editing someone else's profile?

Comment: Whatever you set it to? Pretty sure that was the original issue. `user` used to be global, but people were inadvertently overwriting it in their template code, so we changed the global to `currentUser`.