# Edit a checkbox field within table field from the front end

Tags: templating, form

This is an extension of a question I posted [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/edit-a-table-field-type-from-the-front-end) earlier, but another layer of complexity.

I'm trying to have a checkbox field *within* a table field be checked/unchecked from a front end form.

I've tried a number of scenarios using the example found [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/checkboxes-fields#templating) in the docs, but no dice.

Here is my current code:

```
    <table>
      {% for row in currentUser.providerPayment %}
    <tr>
        <td>Sliding scale?</td>

        {% for slidingScale in currentUser.providerPayment  %}
            {% set checked = false %}

            {% if slidingScale.selected %}
                {% set checked = true %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if not checked %}
                <input type="hidden" name="fields[providerPayment][0][col2]" value="">
            {% endif %}

            <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ slidingScale.value }}" name="fields[providerPayment][0][col2]" {% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
   </table>
```

And here is the error it's producing:

[image]

**Update** Here are my table field settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Table field’s settings?

Comment: Updated with the table field settings

Comment: Not sure I’m following - there’s no checkbox column in there?

Comment: Ah, I had the wrong screenshot attached. It's updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you do this:

```
{% for row in currentUser.providerPayment %}

    ...

    {% for slidingScale in currentUser.providerPayment %}
```

you’re looping through the `currentUser.providerPayment` array (the rows in your providerPayment Table field on the current user) within another loop through the same array. If the table has 2 rows, this is what would be happening:

- Row 1 (assigned to `row`)

  - Row 1 (assigned to `slidingScale`)
  - Row 2 (assigned to `slidingScale`)
- Row 2 (assigned to `row`)

  - Row 1 (assigned to `slidingScale`)
  - Row 2 (assigned to `slidingScale`)

(Doesn’t make any sense.)

You only need a single for-loop here, and it’s the outer one. Within that loop, you will be able to access all of the values on the current row, via the `row` variable you’ve defined:

```
{% for row in currentUser.providerPayment %}

    {{ row.averageCostPerSession }}
    {{ row.slidingScale }}
    {{ row.acceptedPaymentMethods }}
    {{ row.acceptedInsuranceCarriers }}

{% endfor %}
```

Does that make sense?

So, for each row, if you want to output a checkbox input, you would just do this:

```
{% for row in currentUser.providerPayment %}
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1"
            name="fields[providerPayment][0][col2]"
            {% if row.sliderScale %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

One thing to keep in mind with checkboxes, though, is that they don’t actually submit any POST data if left unchecked. So to be safe, you should put a hidden input right before the checkbox input, with a blank value, which will act as the default value if the checkbox is left unchecked:

```
{% set name = 'fields[providerPayment][0][col2]' %}

{% for row in currentUser.providerPayment %}
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ name }}" value="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ name }}" value="1"
            {% if row.sliderScale %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```